# i am trying to auto update time id if time is passed

Tags: javascript, php, time

Select Time :

```
    <option value="1^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:20 AM</option>
    <option value="3^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:40 AM</option>
    <option value="4^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="5^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:20 AM</option>
    <option value="6^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:40 AM</option>
    <option value="7^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="8^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:20 AM</option>
    <option value="9^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:40 AM</option>
    <option value="10^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="11^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:20 PM</option>
    <option value="12^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:40 PM</option>
    <option value="13^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:20 PM</option>
    <option value="15^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:40 PM</option>
    <option value="16^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:20 PM</option>
    <option value="18^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:40 PM</option>
    <option value="19^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:20 PM</option>
    <option value="21^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:40 PM</option>
    <option value="22^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:20 PM</option>
    <option value="24^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:40 PM</option>
    <option value="25^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:00 PM</option>
    <option value="26^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:20 PM</option>
    <option value="27^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:40 PM</option>
    <option value="28^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:00 PM</option>
    <option value="29^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:20 PM</option>
    <option value="30^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:40 PM</option>
    <option value="31^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:00 PM</option>
    <option value="32^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:20 PM</option>
    <option value="33^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:40 PM</option>
    <option value="34^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:00 PM</option>
    <option value="35^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:20 PM</option>
    <option value="36^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:40 PM</option>
    <option value="37^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:00 PM</option>
    <option value="38^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:20 PM</option>
    <option value="39^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:40 PM</option>
    </select>
```

function updateCouponTime(passedValue){ myArray=passedValue.split('^'); document.getElementById('time_id').value=myArray[0]; document.getElementById('date').value=myArray[1]; }

Comment: i have give timeid to all from 1 to 39

Comment: Don't you want to add your question to your ..... question? Please add some more information to your question, like your JavaScript code or what you want to do?!

Comment: this are the drop down for coupon time, i want time should get selected according to time interval. e.g. if it 9:21am to 9:39:59am the time selected should be 9:40am

Comment: function updateCouponTime(passedValue){
myArray=passedValue.split('^');
document.getElementById('time_id').value=myArray[0];
document.getElementById('date').value=myArray[1];
}

Comment: Why are you adding your info bit by bit?!? Please update your post and add all your info at once. All of your `html` and you `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

Select Time :

```
    <option value="1^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:20 AM</option>
    <option value="3^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:40 AM</option>
    <option value="4^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="5^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:20 AM</option>
    <option value="6^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">10:40 AM</option>
    <option value="7^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="8^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:20 AM</option>
    <option value="9^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">11:40 AM</option>
    <option value="10^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="11^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:20 PM</option>
    <option value="12^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">12:40 PM</option>
    <option value="13^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:00 PM</option>
    <option value="14^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:20 PM</option>
    <option value="15^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">01:40 PM</option>
    <option value="16^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:00 PM</option>
    <option value="17^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:20 PM</option>
    <option value="18^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">02:40 PM</option>
    <option value="19^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:00 PM</option>
    <option value="20^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:20 PM</option>
    <option value="21^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">03:40 PM</option>
    <option value="22^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:00 PM</option>
    <option value="23^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:20 PM</option>
    <option value="24^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">04:40 PM</option>
    <option value="25^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:00 PM</option>
    <option value="26^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:20 PM</option>
    <option value="27^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">05:40 PM</option>
    <option value="28^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:00 PM</option>
    <option value="29^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:20 PM</option>
    <option value="30^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">06:40 PM</option>
    <option value="31^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:00 PM</option>
    <option value="32^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:20 PM</option>
    <option value="33^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">07:40 PM</option>
    <option value="34^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:00 PM</option>
    <option value="35^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:20 PM</option>
    <option value="36^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">08:40 PM</option>
    <option value="37^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:00 PM</option>
    <option value="38^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:20 PM</option>
    <option value="39^<?php echo date("d/m/y")?>;">09:40 PM</option>
    </select>
```

function updateCouponTime(passedValue){ myArray=passedValue.split('^'); document.getElementById('time_id').value=myArray[0]; document.getElementById('date').value=myArray[1]; }

Comment: coupon time gets change if selected manually, but i want current time slot should get selected automatically. for e.g if current time is 10:15. so coupon time should be 10:20. interval of every 20 mins.